# R Chart Repeats itself

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I am trying to use R to draw a chart.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Ind <- read_csv("Industrial.csv")

Ind1 <- Ind %>%
  select(Period,Year,City,Sub_Market,GeoLevel7,Property_Type,Average_Equivalent_Yield_Prime_Grade) %>%
  filter(Sub_Market == "Sydney Metro" & GeoLevel7 == "South Sydney" & Property_Type == "Distribution Warehouse/Logistics")%>%
  unite(Time,Period,Year,sep=".")

ggplot(data=Ind1, aes(x=Time, y=Average_Equivalent_Yield_Prime_Grade,group=1)) +
  geom_line(color="#aa0022", size=1) +
  geom_point(color="#aa0022", size=1) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("Q1.1976","Q1.1981","Q1.1986","Q1.1991","Q1.1996","Q1.2001","Q1.2006","Q1.2011","Q1.2016","Q1F.2021","Q1F.2026")) +
  ggtitle("South Sydney Cap Rates") +
  labs(x="", y="(%)") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=12, family="Times", color="#666666")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12, family="Times")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, family="Times", face="bold", hjust=0, color="#666666")
```

My issue is that the output is a chart that appears to repeat itself.

**Screenshot of chart outcome**

[image]

I am struggling to work out why this is happening. I have written the data table to a CSV file and have drawn it in Excel to get this result.

**Excel Chart Screenshot**

[image]

Some of the data is not available hence the broken lines in Excel, is this the cause of the R issue?

A sample of the Ind1 tibble is as below [Image of Ind1 tibble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eySPe.png). Sorry I am not sure how to insert a table or CSV file  of the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you be able to provide a minimal sample data? Then, SO users can look into your case and provide some supports for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a screenshot of the data. Probably best in a table or csv file but not sure how to add that in the comment box?

Comment: Can your type dput(Ind) in R console? Then you’ll see some texts there. That’s your data.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your second post, you probably have some difficulties in creating a sample data. So I had a look of your image and create a minimal sample data. You will need to modify my code in a way it works for you.

I noticed that you do not have all four quarters in each year. So, you need to create a full data set. `Time` contains year and quarter. I extracted characters for each using `substr()`. In order to have a full data set, I used `complete()`. By this time, you have all four quarters for each year. For a labeling purpose, I updated `Time`, which contain year and quarter information.

Now you have a clean data set. You can draw a figure. I simplified your code. You need to add whatever you want to complete your task. Finally, if you need to produce a sample data, use `dput()`. Have a look of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- data.frame(Time = c("Q1.1977", "Q2.1977", "Q3.1977", "Q4.1977",
                            "Q1.1978", "Q2.1978", "Q3.1978", "Q4.1978",
                            "Q2.2015", "Q3.2015", "Q4.2015"),
                   GeoLevel = "South Sydney",
                   Average = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.63, 9.61, 9.58,
                               6.88, 6.63, 6.38),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


mutate(mydf,
       Quarter = substr(Time, 1, 2),
       Time = substr(Time, 4, 7)) %>%
complete(Time, nesting(Quarter), fill = list(Average = NA)) %>%
mutate(Time = paste(Time, Quarter, sep = "-")) -> out


ggplot(data = out, aes(x = Time, y = Average)) +
geom_point() +
geom_path(group = 1, color = "red") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]